# Merge two recordset in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, merge

I have following 2 recordsets :

Recordset 1:

```
Id  isVal  isVal1
1   Y      N
2   Y      N
```

Recordset 2:

```
Id  isVal  isVal1
2   N      Y
3   N      Y
```

Actual recordset required is:

```
Id  isVal  isVal1
1  Y       N
2  Y       Y
3  N       Y
```

Should I use join? Can you please advice me how can I solve this?

Comment: When looking at `Id = 2`, which value do you want for `isVal`? `Y` as specified in Recordset 1, or `N` as in Recordset 2? Do Recordset 1 values always have priority over Recordset 2 values? Or `Y` always have priority over `N` if the `Id` exists in both tables?

Answer (score 1):

No, you want to place the records on top of each other so you would need to use `union`.

```
select id, max(isval) as isval, max(isval1) as isval1
  from ( select id, isval, isval1
           from recordset1
          union all
         select id, isval, isval1
           from recordset1
                )
 group by id
```

I use `union all` as you don't need to remove duplicates, for which you would remove the `all`.

The `max` works because `'Y'` is "greater" than `'N'`.

I'm assuming that `'Y'` takes precedence over `'N'` rather than values from the first record-set are less important than values from the second.